# How do I get a value from a database of an element that is linked to another one with foreign key?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have these models that are linked with a foreign key

```
class Student(models.Model):
   id_student = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
   date_of_birth = models.DateField()
   nationality = models.CharField(max_length=45)
   gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)
   street_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
   street_number = models.CharField(max_length=45)
   postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=45)
   city = models.CharField(max_length=45)
   phone = models.CharField(max_length=45)
   email = models.CharField(max_length=45)
   study_id_study = models.ForeignKey('Study', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='study_id_study')
   start_year = models.CharField(max_length=45)
   teacher_id_teacher = models.ForeignKey('Teacher', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='teacher_id_teacher', related_name = 'tcr_id')

   class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'Student'


class Teacher(models.Model):
    id_teacher = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    street_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    street_number = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    salary = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    study_counselor = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    picture_url = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Teacher'
```

I wanted to get the name of the teacher depending on teacher_id_teacher that we have in Student model, and which is foreign key as well

seems easy but I have been trying to do this for two days with no success,

Thanks you so much :)

Comment: As simple as
s = Student.objects.get(id=1);
print(s.teacher_id_teacher.first_name)

Comment: @RishiDev sorry, it actually worked, thank you so much :D